# Using Resharper Unit Test Runner for MSTest via Gallio

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mstest, gallio

I am attempting to get the [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) test runner to recognize my MSTest unit tests via [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/).

I have the following installed:
VSTS 2005 8.0.50727.762
Resharper 4.1
Gallio 3.0.0.285

I am also running Windows XP x64.

The unit test options only shows NUnit as being available. I am thinking that I must have some versioning wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction? Am I barking up the wrong tree and this is only works in VS2k8?

**UPDATE:** Well I updated Gallio to GallioBundle-3.0.4.385-Setup and it now shows up in the unit test options for R#. But I get the following error when running tests in either R# or Icarus:

> Failures Cannot 
>   run tests because the
>   MSTest executable was not found

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a Gallio problem. It appears to only support the version of MSTest that comes with VS2k8. The XML format for vsmdi has changed between versions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this applies to your question, but the latest news on the Gallio site states :

> **Gallio and ReSharper 4.0**
>   A few people have asked when Gallio will
>   support the final release of ReSharper
>   4.0. Unfortunately there were some last-minute breaking changes between
>   ReSharper 4.0 Beta and the Final
>   release. So the ReSharper plugin in
>   Gallio Alpha 3 Update 2 will not work
>   anymore. No matter... we plan to
>   release another update of Gallio later
>   this week.

**Update:** just saw this applied to an earlier version than you were using so disregard that.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper 4.5 supports MSTest out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a MSTest ReSharper plugin that was recently released:
http://www.sneal.net/blog/2009/01/24/MSTestReSharper4Plugin.aspx

I've been able to use it successfully with ReSharper 4.1 on Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: That plugin now supports ReSharper 4.5: http://www.sneal.net/blog/2009/09/10/ReSharper45MsTestPlugin.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not need resharper to support standalone mstest installation. I explain how to make a standalone mstest installation without the VS in my post here - http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/running-mstest-without-visual-studio