# Using ReSharper Test Runner to run MSTest Unit Tests

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, resharper, mstest, gallio

I need to use the ReSharper Unit Test Runner to run my MSTest Unit Tests on VS 2008.  I have heard of using "Gallio" to do this but I don't know what Gallio is (it seemed like some all purpose VS extensibility framework).  Does anyone know the best way to run MSTest Unit Tests using ReSharper Test Runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

[Using Resharper Unit Test Runner for MSTest via Gallio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94057/using-resharper-unit-test-runner-for-mstest-via-gallio)

and

http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/IntroducingVstsUnitPluginForReSharper.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Note, that ReSharper 4.5 which you can get via Early Access Program, is going to support MSTest out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the latest ReSharper 4.5 nightly build (27 Feb 2009/#1181) and it works pretty well but I have to explictly add the tests or fixtures to a unit test session. I can't run all tests from the project or solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need resharper to support standalone mstest installation. I explain how to make a standalone mstest installation without the VS in my post here - http://www.shunra.com/shunrablog/index.php/2009/04/running-mstest-without-visual-studio